# How _quickly_ disable all keyboard layouts, except default? Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I have three languages and four keyboard layouts on my Windows 10.

Most of the time I need only one language and one keyboard (default, "US-EN") for my main work.

Is there any way (using Windows or some free software) to toggle between 2 states:

**State 1** - Only one language and layout
**State 2** - Everything is enabled

I've tried with saving and then importing of registry entries, but even this clumsy approach does not work...
*Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout*

Comment: Why do you care if the extra layouts are there?

Comment: Having additional languages enabled is very annoying. It takes some additional mental space. And even if you're accurate enough, there are many cases where I want to have only one language and not accidentally type in another.
Moreover, one of layouts is not-Latin based and I would like to switch it off during working hours completely.